# Do any philosophers say surreal numbers are reason to doubt platonism?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request, foundations-of-mathematics, platonism

Not trying to be inflammatory at all, this is a genuine (maybe dumb) question.

Especially in regards to the genesis of the surreals, which was Conway thinking about Go endgames. They seem among the least platonic numbers/mathematical objects. They have the benefits of down to earth construction but also the capabilities of the reals and beyond.

I also can’t find what Conway thought about platonism if anyone knows.

I imagine some philosopher must have said something about them in regards to ontology.

Comment: I haven't gone over the details at all, but I think Hamkins uses surreal numbers in one of his essays. He's a Platonic realist. What do you mean by "down to earth construction"? Having nontrivial division, root extraction, logarithms, and other things besides, applying to transfinite ordinals, amazes me, and I wouldn't say it's more or less "Platonic" than if we didn't have these operations on those numbers, but I'm wondering what the criteria are for comparing the degrees of Platonism respecting various mathematical categories.

Comment: @KristianBerry In the same way Hartry Field said something like in Science Without Numbers,  “when the chips are down…we can do physics without numbers”, because we can use non-abstract, concrete, physical and linguistic objects. Aren’t “go endgames” “down to earth constructions” and non-abstract objects? That is, when using surreals one may always have in mind they are using a linguistic or physical tools based on games, which are physical and concrete.

Comment: Maybe less a matter of *ante rem* and more an *in re* realism (or construably so), but an interesting paper could be [this one on ultratasks](https://philarchive.org/archive/ALDSTA). [Another paper](http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~rmiller/Ehrlich.pdf) relates **No** as the proper class of surreals to NBG theory and talks about an "absolute" kind of continuum (that word "absolute" indicating, though not implying, a transcendentally absolute *ante rem* reality).

Comment: The epigraph for the second essay also suggests a more peculiar idea, something like modal neo-logicism, though addressing all that would mean clearer and more useful distinctions between abstract and concrete information, the status of 'mere *possibilia*', etc.

Comment: @KristianBerry those are probably above my understanding but the second has section of links for building up a background thanks

Comment: Kadvany makes such a point in his [review of Badiou's Numbers and numbers](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/number-and-numbers/):"*Badiou would like to think that Conway's surreal numbers, being "constitutive" of ordinals, real numbers, and their wild arithmetic, avoids that constructivist stain... But surreal numbers don't arise from dust, they rely on combinatorial rules via Conway's game-theoretic constructs, and these are axioms manqué. Computation and symbolic manipulation cannot be ignored because every formalism relies on them.*"

Comment: @Conifold Thanks so much. At least that opinion is out there. And someone finds it interesting enough to write about.

Comment: @Conifold: Surreal numbers form the largest ordered field, a proper class. Thus the surreal numbers cannot be constructivist as they must rely on some way on the axiom of choice. Another argument:  The reals rely on it and they are a proper subfield of the surreals. Badiou can sometimes be very bizarre in his understanding of mathematics. Also, by conviction he is a materialist - amd so will deny any form of Platonism, including mathematical one by conviction. It's his political committments I admire, for example on Palestine, the  War on Terror, on Capitalism. On these he is a hardcore ...

Comment: @Conifold: ... Marxist.

Comment: @Conifold: What exactly is Kadavny's point? Can you explain further?

Comment: @Conifold: Perhaps Kadavny means post-structuralist rather than constructivist? Maybe pick your refs more carefully - or just throw them into the dustbin of history LOL.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of mathematicians consciously hold on to Mathematical Platonism. For example, Penrose in *The Emperor's New Mind* said there appears:

> to be some profound reality about these mathematical concepts, going quite beyond the mental deliberations of any particular mathematician. It is as though human thought is, instead, being guided towards some external truth - a trith which has a reality of its own.

Others hold it unconsciously. Fir example, Eugenia Cheng has said in a paper that when she thinks about it, then she doesn't think numbers or triangles live in some Platonic realm but when she goes about her daily work as a mathematician, this is exactly how she treats it: they're there, they exist.

Now the surreal thing about mathematical platonism is that all mathematical concepts are at the same ontological level. Plato himself placed it between the matter of the world and his higher id3as/forms.

Thus for mathematical platonism, there is no difference between surreal numbers or the ordinary integers: like 1, 2, 3 ...

.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136234/discussion-on-answer-by-mozibur-ullah-do-any-philosophers-say-surreal-numbers-ar).